# (C++) string literal doesn't match argument list

Tags: c++, class, constructor, char, arguments

I'm following along with a C++ book titled "Starting Out with C++: From Control Structures Through Objects" by Tony Gaddis.

There's a programming example that I get an error on. The program creates a constructor for a class which takes two arguments. The two arguments are pointers to chars. Here's part of the class:

```
class ContactInfo
{
private:
    char *name;
    char *phone;
public:
    ContactInfo(char *n, char *p)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
        phone = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
        strcpy(name, n);
        strcpy(phone, p);
    }
}
```

When an object of the ContactInfo class is created, the program passes these values to the constructor.

```
ContactInfo entry("Kristen Lee", "555-2021");
```

This all seems to make sense to me, but I get an error when passing "Kristen Lee" to the constructor. The error says:

"no instance of constructor "ContactInfo::ContactInfo" matches the argument list. Argument types are: (const char[12], const char[9])"

I don't understand why this error shows up. The only thing I can think of is that we're trying to pass a value into a variable which holds memory addresses. But, I don't know enough about programming to know if this is the case. I doubt this would be in the textbook if it didn't work at all. Maybe it's a visual studio problem (the IDE I'm using)? I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this problem.

Comment: String literals (your arguments) are `const`; those parameters,`ContactInfo(char *n, char *p)`,  are not. Therefore, there is match. Frankly, if allowed for whatever this is destined, `std::string` would be preferential for most of this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A string literal (e.g. `"Kristen Lee"`) is a `const char*`: it is unmodifiable by your program. Since the constructor of `ContactInfo` takes only a `char*`, the string literal does not match.

This is laid out in the compiler message:

> no instance of constructor "ContactInfo::ContactInfo" matches the argument list. **Argument types are: (const char[12], const char[9])**

Here the compiler is telling you there's no match for the function `ContactInfo::ContactInfo` and that the arguments you're passing as `const char[12]` and `const char[9]`.

Your problem can be very easily solved by using `std::string` instead:

```
#include <string>
class ContactInfo
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string phone;
public:
    ContactInfo(std::string n, std::string p) : name{n}, phone{p}
    {}
};
```

Notice how much simpler that makes your code, as you no longer need 4 lines of code and to manage your own memory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue got fixed when I changed the constructor argument list is (const char *n, const char *p). Using std::string is the better solution, I just wanted to write the program in the way that was shown in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

A string literal can decay to a `char const*`, not a `char*`. Hence, you should change your constructor to use `char const*`.

```
ContactInfo(char const* n, char const* p) { ... }
```

As a general principle, unless you want a function to modify its argument, make it `const`. That's always a better choice. It allows the function to be used using a `const` object and a non-`const` object. This applies to passing pointers as well as references to objects.